# jquery display letter one by one with time out

Tags: jquery, each, letter

I tried to split alle letters and display one by one with timeout. I found some solution but they seem not working for me.

This script appends a complete layer (word) but jumps over the each loop. The message is a string named Hello!

```js
Plugin.prototype.message = function(message) {
    var word = '<div class="word">';
    var letters = message.toString().split('');

    $.each(letters, function (i, letter) {
        //alert displays letter properly one by one
        setTimeout(function () {
            word += letter;
        }, 30);

    });

    word += '</div>';
    $('#chat-layer').append(word);
    $('.word').animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 200 );
}
```

Has anybody an idea, how to solve this?

Comment: Well, `word += letter` just adds the `letter` to `word`; it doesn't update the HTML. You need to update the HTML in the loop.

Comment: As above: you only create the word after you've changed the html.  It's not *"jumping over the each loop"* - it's running the content later, as you've requested with your setTimeout.  You need to add each letter to the html one at a time, not a word at a time.  Here's your code updated to be 1 letter at a time: https://jsfiddle.net/uyv4c1bs/

Answer (score 1):

I just make this code to demonstrate chained executing of timers for letter by letter output (in your example all timers will be scheduled asynchronously after 30 ms from the one moment).

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="output">
</div>
<script>
    var str = new String("The new string to display letter by letter"); // display this string
    var interval = 500; // interval for each letter in ms
    var letters = str.split("");
    var cnt = 0;
    
    var f = function(){
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML + (letters[cnt] == " " ? "&nbsp;" : letters[cnt]);
        if (cnt++<(letters.length-1)) {
            setTimeout(f, interval);
        }
    }
    f(); // first invoke
</script>
</body>
</html>
```